# Switching graphics card - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, graphics

I have an Optiplex 7010 in which I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 (after using Windows with Intel HD graphics), and by default the active graphics card is listed below by the output of:

```
sudo lshw -C display
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

But I want to switch to Intel HD Graphics,because it has better performance than the other. I've searched a lot in web about how to switch them, but I found nothing that solved my situation, I found this article https://support.system76.com/articles/graphics-switch-ubuntu/ but didn't worked out. In addition I found an article related to list all the available GPU's by installing mesa-utils package and executing:

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x55 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:CAICOS @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```

As you can see it only detects one but as I mentioned earier i used to use Intel HD. I append the Optiplex Video specifications from https://www1.la.dell.com/mx/es/corp/Computadora-y-Todo-en-uno/optiplex-7010/pd.aspx?refid=optiplex-7010&s=corp

Video6
Gráficos Intel®  HD 2500/4000 integrados (CPU Core i3/i5/i7 de tercera generación)

Gráficos Intel®  HD integrados (CPU de doble núcleo Celeron® /Pentium® )

Opción de gráficos discretos AMD RADEON HD 7570 de 1 GB

Opción de gráficos discretos AMD RADEON HD 7470 de 1 GB

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to remove the Radeon HD 7470/8470 card? I very much doubt an Intel GPU has better performance, by the way.

Comment: No I have not tried, however i do not know if disabling it may cause some crashes as it is the only card that is detected... And about the performance I checked in user benchmark those specific model of gpu's and intel's is better. I think I'll just go ahead and buy a new pc. -Thank you very much for answering :D